# Deep merge order maps in Go

Tags: dictionary, go, merge

I am reading two YAML files, one is considered the "base" and one the "environment". I need to unmarshal them as ordered maps and merge them, retaining the order.

So if baseline looks like this:

```
key1: baseline
key2:
  subkey1: baseline
  subkey2:
    subsubkey1: baseline
```

And the environment looks like this:

```
key2:
  subkey2:
    subsubkey1: environment
```

I want the resultant map to look like this

```
key1: baseline
key2:
  subkey1: baseline
  subkey2:
    subsubkey1: environment
```

I have tried to use yaml.MapSlice{} but it is essentially an array of arrays and you cannot really merge that.

With Ruby I can use activesupport's deep_merge() and get the desired result and get similar using Python's Collections.OrderedDict. Finding anything in Go has been difficult. I get people dismissing it by saying Go is designed this way.

That's all well and good, but I need the functionality for my project.

Comment: Never try it, but I hope this give you some hints: https://github.com/imdario/mergo.

Comment: It'll merge but the order is lost.

Comment: @gdanko unfortunately for you the order of Go's built in `map`s is random. You'll have to use a different data type. https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_7.

Comment: @gdanko you may want to consider trying a plain old struct, If the yaml package has similar behaviour to other marshaling/unmarshaling packages then this ought to be simple. You first unmarshal the baseline file into your struct, and then the environment file. The second unmarshal should overwrite only those fields that are provided in the environment file, and leave the other ones, those from the first unmarshal, unchanged. (This is only how I think it should work, I haven't used the yaml package, so I don't actually know for sure.)

Comment: @mkopriva the problem is that the "schema" will change based on the file.

Comment: The iteration order needs to be the insertion order. Go yaml has something called yaml.MapSlice{} which is essentially an array of arrays. If I can find a way to flatten that into something like: [key1: baseline, key2.subkey1: baseline], etc I may be able to create my own ordered merge.

Comment: @gdanko depending on how radical the difference between the schemas is, this may not be a problem at all. Looking at the two files in your example this shouldn't really be an issue. Again I haven't used yaml so I'm not sure, but, with json for example, this is very much doable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177132/discussion-between-gdanko-and-mkopriva).